# Argument not realized in a function with filter but there is no error message

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

This is a problem I have encountered before and always chose a workaround, but no more!
I want to bring an argument into my function for `filter`, but it does not work correctly. I suspect it has something to do with quotation marks but I do not get it right. Let me explain the problem in an example:

```r
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% filter(am > 0)
```

Filters as intended.
Let's make a corresponding function.

```
fun_a <- function(b) {
  mtcars %>%
  filter(b > 0)
}
```

And test it.

```r
fun_a(am)
```

Throws error:

```r
Error: object 'am' not found
```

Another try.

```r
fun_a("am")
```

No error, but does not filter either. 
What is happening here?

I found an example that illustrates very well *what is happening here*:

```r
mtcars %>% mutate(ex = am)
```

This gets you a column named ex that is a copy of `mtcars$am`:

```r
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb ex
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  1
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  0
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  0
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  0
```

```r
fun_f <- function(f){
  mtcars %>% mutate(ex = f)
}

fun_f("am")
```

And from this you get a new column ex filled with *am*, literally:

```r
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb ex
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 am
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 am
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 am
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 am
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 am
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 am
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `b` is not considered as part of the dataframe in the function's context.

You can use `get`:

```
fun_a <- function(b) {  
  mtcars %>%
  filter(get(b) > 0)
}
fun_a("am")
```

Comment: Could you expand on why this is not seen as column of the dataframe? What else could be expected in this context? And why is there no error message with "another try"? I'd really like to understand what the problem is here. `function` is obviously more complicated as I thought. Why is not _b_ just replaced with _am?_

Comment: In your `another try` "am" is a character vector of length 1 (which is > 0), always `TRUE` so no filter

Comment: I understand I should not use comments for that, but I have to say: "Ahhhh!"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass as unquoted variable one way using rlang's curly curly (`{{}}`) operator would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

fun_a <- function(b) {
  mtcars %>% filter({{b}} > 0)
}

fun_a(am)

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#8  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#9  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#10 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#11 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#12 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#13 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

However, it is a good practice to pass dataframe as well in the function

```
fun_a <- function(df, b) {
  df %>% filter({{b}} > 0)
}

fun_a(mtcars, am)
```

---

If you want to pass it as quoted variable, we can do

```
fun_a <- function(df, b) {
   df[df[b] > 0, ]
}

fun_a(mtcars, "am")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)    
fun_a <- function(b) {
    mtcars %>%
        filter(!! enquo(b) > 0)
  }

fun_a(am)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#8  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#9  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#10 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#11 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#12 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#13 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

---

If we are passing a quoted variable

```
fun_b <- function(b) {
      mtcars %>%
         filter_at(vars(b), all_vars(. > 0))
     }
fun_b("am")
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the "proper" `dplyr` idiom is to use `quasiquotation`:

```
fun_a <- function(b) {
  b <- enquo(b)
  mtcars %>% filter(!!b > 0)
}
```